# Programmatically trigger click event of button on Android

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, android-tv, ionic3

I'm currectly working on Android TV controls in Ionic 3.3.0 with Cordova 7.0.1. Since the device has no touchscreen I have to use the remote control. I'm using

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  // Check the key code and determine the next element to focus
  // ...

  // Focus the element
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(nextElement._elementRef.nativeElement,'focus');
}
```

to check for remote control pushes to change focus. This works fine. When the enter key is pressed I want that the click action of the button is activated. Now i tried using something like

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if(event.key == 'Enter') {
    var focusedButton = Helper.getCurrentlyFocusedButton();
    focusedButton._elementRef.nativeElement.click();
    // Using the debugger I know that these lines are triggered, but nothing happens
  }
}
```

to programmatically press the button. This works fine when using ionic serve with Chrome but doesn't work on the Android device (Sony KD-49XD7005 with Android TV 6.0.1). As far as i could gather from googling, this is because click is not supported. But there must be another way to trigger this event? I also tried to create touch events manually

```
var e1 = document.createEvent('TouchEvent'); // Also tried 'UIEvent'
e1.initEvent('touchstart', true, true);

var e2 = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
e2.initEvent('touchend', true, true);

this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(focusedButton._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [e1]);
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(focusedButton._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [e2]);

// Also tried
// focusedButton._elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(e1);
// focusedButton._elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(e2);
```

but ultimately nothing worked. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by looking at the source code of ionic-angular. In the file `node_modules/ionic-angular/tap-click/tap-click.js` is a method that handles the `click` event. It calls another method called `shouldCancelClick(ev)` which returns `true` when `this.dispatchClick` is undefined or false. `this.dispatchClick` is set by `pointerStart(ev)` which is bound to the `mousedown` event.

So all that has to be done is to trigger a `mousedown` event before triggering the `click` event.

I solved it like this:

```
var e1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e1.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
focusedButton.dispatchEvent(e1);

var e2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e2.initEvent('click', true, true);
focusedButton.dispatchEvent(e2);
```